# Using Glyphfriend with bower

Tags: css, visual-studio-2015

I've modified my VS 2015 project to remove the existing Bootstrap and FontAwesome NuGet packages in favor of getting those CSS libraries from bower.  I've discovered that I can get CSS Intellisense working for those CSS classes by including the `bootstrap.css` and `font-awesome.css` files (several sub-folders deep under the `bower_components` project folder) in the VS project.

But I haven't yet figured out the magic to get the Glyphfriend extension to work in this configuration.  Simply including `bower_components/dist/css/bootstrap.css` in the project satisfies Intellisense, but it doesn't get me icon pictures via Glyphfriend.  I've tried including the svg files in the project, but that doesn't help.  I've also tried copying the svg files to their previous home in the `Fonts` project folder, but that didn't help either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Glyphfriend gods fixed it.